# Increment Pointer in Delphi / Create stream from pointer

Tags: delphi, pointers

**Short form:** Is it possible to create a stream from a pointer?

I have a pointer which points to file data I need to read. I used WriteBuffer() to transfer data from the pointer to a TFileStream, which works. But now I want to read it block wise to display a progress bar. So I need to read it step by step.

I have to options:

1) Increment the pointer Buff, and use WriteBuffer() as usual. (WriteBuffer always reads from the beginning, therefore I need to increment the pointer)

2) Create a Stream from the pointer. Is this possible?

Code:

```
var InputStream : TMemoryStream;
    Buff: Pointer;


    Header: TOCHeader;
begin

// Here I get the pointer
Size := GetOverlay(Buff);

// Transfer data to memory stream
InputStream.WriteBuffer(Buff^, SizeOf(Header));

InputStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

// Read the header
InputStream.ReadBuffer(Header, SizeOf(Header));

// Increment the pointer. Doesn't work :-(. Message Ordinal type required
Inc(Buff, SizeOf(TOC));
```

Comment: You have two InputStream variables in your code. You both read from it and write to it. Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I've fixed that. I just copied the important variables and code phrases, and the InputStream definition seems to be very important ;-).

Comment: Note that you need to reset the position of the stream between writing to it and reading from it. Your current code would raise an exception.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'll add that to the sourcecode to not confuse others. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question comes up my mind when I read your question. You have a pointer to filedata (from disk I presume?) and you are filling a filestream with data from that pointer (although in your question you're filling a memorystream instead). Why not use a TFileStream to open the file you are reading?

```
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Header: TOCHeader;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('c:\fileIWantToRead.txt', fmOpenRead);
  FileStream.ReadBuffer(Header, SizeOf(Header));
  <...>
end;
```

If you want to increment your pointer, then first cast it to a pointer of a type, so the compiler knows how to increase your pointer.

```
Inc(PByte(Buff), SizeOf(TOC)); //sizeof returns size in bytes, so cast pointer to a bytepointer
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot use TFileStream, because I want to read the data out of the EXE that is currently running to create a self extracting file. Your suggested solution compiles, I will mark it as accepted answer when I also get it to work ;-).

Comment: As you can see in mghie's post, TFileStream is not limited to 'c:\fileIWantToRead.txt' ;), you can also open your exe with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own `TCustomMemoryStream` descendant, which calls `SetPointer()` in the constructor, using the address and size that you receive from `GetOverlay()`. Consult the Delphi documentation of `TCustomMemoryStream` for further information.

**Edit:**

Well, this has nothing to do with your question, but in a comment you write that you only wish to read from the running executable file via a stream. That's easy enough to do:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str: TStream;
begin
  Str := TFileStream.Create(ParamStr(0), fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Caption := Format('Size of executable: %u bytes', [Str.Size]);
    // start to read the contents of the file ...

  finally
    Str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I will leave the original answer, in case somebody really wants to create a (read-only) stream from a pointer to a chunk of memory.

Comment: I tried that when I started implementing my program, but I got an error that the file is currently in use and so I thought it isn't possible... Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have indeed. If you have problems accessing files, try using the SysInternals tools which can show you what other program has the file opened (exclusively).

Comment: I hope you haven't misunderstood my problem: I have to read the exe that is currently running, the Application has to read itself to extract resources out from itsself. (Like an SFX archive...)

Comment: The TFileStream is created with *ParamStr(0)* as the file name, meaning the currently running application. Isn't that what you need to do?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. That's exactly what I need. I use Delphi for the first time, just because I need to write setup bootstrapper which is of course of not possible with C#. (Cause of the framework dependency).

Comment: If you need to read resources out of the currently-running EXE, why not just use Delphi's built-in support for it?  Create a TResourceStream and pass HInstance (handle to the current app) as the first param to the constructor...

Comment: I used TResourceStream before, but the Delphi Linker has problems with big files (250 MB)

Answer (score -1):

TResourceStream would do here...